# Как оценить простоту использования ПО?

Tags: gui, ux

Возникла задача оценить простоту использования программы, причем не просто "сложно-просто", а более объективно... Может быть есть какие-нибудь системы оценки, которые дают конкретное число, оценивающее простоту, скажем по 10-и бальной шкале или что-то в этом роде. Буду благодарен за помощь. (извиняюсь за офф-топ, не знал, какие теги указать :))

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Юзабилити-тестирование

Comment: Так как это очень субъективная оценка, ее сложно привести к функциональным тестам. Тем не менее, вы всегда можете брать какие-то базовые метрики, например, количество действий пользователя для достижения конкретной страницы, и сравнивать их с конкурентами. В идеале вы должны собирать статистику пользования приложением, и уже отталкиваясь от нее строить и проверять гипотезы; без этого вы никогда не узнаете, что треть постоянных пользователей ежедневно заходит на страницу, которой вы не уделяете внимания, считая ее ненужной.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы объективно оценить **простоту использования программы**, посадите за нее пользователя, который видит ее впервые. Дайте пользователю задание (или несколько), которое он должен выполнить **самостоятельно** с помощью этой программы. Замерьте время выполнения. Это и будет объективная оценка **простоты использования программы**.

Comment: Измерение это совершенно правильный подход. Но нельзя только на абсолютного новичка ориентироваться в общем случае. К примеру: одна программа предоставляет возможность записи сценариев, а другая нет. Если дано задание повторить какой-нибудь сценарий для  множества однотипных файлов, то рано или поздно ПО с возможностью создания сценариев победит: то есть для обработки одного файла одно ПО может быть  "проще", если вы его в перый раз видите, но для идентичной обработки каждый день нового файла другое ПО может быть гораздо проще (даже если оно требует  некоторого начального обучения).

Comment: Аналогично, пользователь должен обладать базовой грамотностью в предметной области и аналогичном ПО.

Comment: @jfs Простота использования - это именно насколько быстро пользователь разберется с интерфейсом. Для этого нужен именно новичок. Это именно то, о чем спрашивает автор вопроса.

Comment: @a-bobkov: критерий в ответе: *"Замерьте время выполнения"* Представьте задание: "проверить битые ссылки на сайте" (вариант а) руками в браузере пройтись (вариант б) написать/найти готовый скрипт, который ссылки проверит -- если небольшой сайт один раз, проверить, то проверка в браузере может меньше времени занять, чем больше сайт, чем чаще нужно проверку проводить, тем более вероятно, что использование/написание скрипта победит (меньше времени займёт), даже если в процессе придётся пользователя научить использовать гугл, командную строку, навыки программирования.